# How to handle a html tag 'message-banner' in python selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I come across a html page which has the following code in it:

[image]

This `message-banner` defines a kind of overlay over the actual page with a message in it. I neither do not find a definition for that tag, not am I able to select an existing element as part of this `message-banner`.

Any ideas how I can handle this issue? I cannot provide a more elaborate example as this is from a non-public webpage.

Comment: You can find the 'message-banner' tag using `element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("message-banner")`

Comment: Interestingly I cannot find that element. I get an `NoSuchElementException` error.

Comment: Quite interesting indeed; what about an xpath selector - `//message-banner`, does it match it? I'm pretty sure an xpath's `local-name()` will find anything, but curious does a normal node name does.

Comment: Nothing found. I tried `//message-banner` and `//*[local-name()='message-banner']`.

Comment: When I print put the complete page source, message banner is not been found. But when I open the inspector, I can see it as on the image.

Comment: I know! Its the GODDAMN IFRAMES again!! Something selenium is absolutely incapable of handling.!!! Interested in creating a web test application, MUCH better than selenium?

Comment: How many window handles do you have when the banner is visible?

Comment: Its the iframes. I was inside an iframe, and selenium cannot handle them properly. Bad programming. When I look for the element BEFORE I switch to an iframe all works as expected.

Comment: This is the expected behavior of `<iframe>`, embedding another html document in the current one, the driver scope is on document at a time.

Comment: But it is extremely user-unfriendly of selenium. Not useable. I guess 50% of all questions are because of the stupid iframe sectioning.

Comment: I'm guessing the developers thought making the user to write one line to switch to the iframe and one to switch back is better approach the making selenium able to handle multiple scopes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187473/discussion-between-alex-and-guy).